# Spring-Couchbase auto generated unique ID not for production?

Tags: spring, spring-data, couchbase, uuid, spring-data-couchbase

The [feature documentation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-couchbase/blob/069ceea65c42bcf8ca3f845781363681878a8927/src/main/asciidoc/autokeygeneration.adoc) 
and the [reference document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#couchbase.autokeygeneration.unique) of the spring-data-couchbase module says that the feature of generating IDs, using the build in 'UNIQUE' generation strategy shall only be used for test scaffolding. This statement is given without an explanation.

Why shall this method not be suitable for production?

---

Example usage:

```
@Document
class Entity(
             @Id
             @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationStrategy.UNIQUE)
             val id: String?,
             @Version
             val version: String?,
             @CreatedDate
             val creationTime: LocalDateTime?
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Writes in couchbase are asynchronous by default, same with views and indexes. But, if you need strong consistency (read after you write ) you should get the document by its key.

So, if you rely on the database to autogenerate they key for you, you will need to wait until the document is actually persisted in the database in order to get the generated id back. This wait can increase significantly your overall write throughput.

Generate your own ids is also considered a good practice, but please, avoid generating sequential ones (owasp security flaw - sequential ids).

This is the code I use for id generation:

```
public String generateId(Class t) {
    return t.getSimpleName()+"--"+UUID.randomUUID().toString()+UUID.randomUUID().toString();
}
```

Comment: As far ais i know Couchbase itself isn´t even capable of generating keys on its own. The generation is performed by the Spring persistence layer. The question here still is: why is this autogenerated Key not designed for production environments?

Comment: If you need sequential ids, you could use couchbase atomic counter for instance. The thing about the autogenerated ids is simply because it might not be the best strategy for your application. For instance, if you add features of your document to its key, you can filter in the future which documents are going to be replicated using XDCR. https://dzone.com/articles/deep-dive-on-cross-data-center-replication-xdcr.

Comment: This still does not answers the question why the default autogenerated key of spring shall not be suitable for standard  production environments since you also provided an example that could be used as valid ID that is independent form the documents content and features. Beside I wonder why you´re going to concatenate two UUIDs.

Comment: @MarkusSpöri You are right that the spring layer generates the UUID keys. It makes sense to have the key name deterministic for future direct document access. It might also help with storage lookup and caching as couchbase uses B+ tree based structure when key ids of a particular format are accessed in a short span (but I'm not quite confident about this part, a couchbase storage team member can help on that).